# Does the following have a solution for f(x,y)?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have the following equations:
\begin{equation}
{1\over f(x,y)} {\partial f(x,y) \over \partial x} \alpha(x,y)
+ {1\over f(x,y)} {\partial f(x,y) \over \partial y} \beta(x,y) = \gamma(x,y)
\end{equation}
Where $\alpha(x,y)$, $\beta(x,y)$ and $\gamma(x,y)$ are exactly known functions. What I need to find is $f(x,y)$. Can anyone help me find a solution? Or are there any assumptions (other than $f(x,y) = g(x)h(y)$ that will allow me to solve this analytically? Is it a standard equation that I haven't come across? Many thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

This is a standard first order partial differential equation, easily solved in principle, if not in practice, by the method of characteristics. Basically, you consider the dynamical system
$$\dot x=\alpha(x,y),\quad \dot y=\beta(x,y)$$
and find that along the trajectories of this dynamical system you have
$$\dot f(x,y)=\gamma(x,y)f(x,y),$$
where $$\dot f(x,y)=\frac{d}{dt}f(x(t),y(t)).$$

Answer (score 0):

Lagrange's method may help you. However, in order to find $f$ analytically, you first need to solve the ODE $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\beta(x, y)}{\alpha(x, y)}$$ analytically. This can happen when $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are taken suitably. Second, if possible, after solving the above ODE you will find an implicit solution $\phi(x, y)=c$ = arbitrary constant, from which you need to make sure that $x$ or $y$ can be solved in terms of one another.